# Create a vector of ofstreams

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to create a vector of ofstreams..

```
vector<ofstream> streams;
for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++){
  ofstream out;
  string fileName = "text" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
  output.open(fileName.c_str());
  streams.push_back(out);
}
```

This code will not compile.. specifically the last line where I attempt to add the ofstream to my vector is generating an error. What am I overlooking?

Comment: This fails because `ofstream` does not have a copy constructor.

Comment: I think you can move one, though?

Answer (score 18):

If you can use C++11 you can use `std::move`, if not just store pointers (smart pointers) in vector.

```
streams.push_back(std::move(out));
```

or with smart ptrs

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<ofstream> > streams;
for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++){
  std::shared_ptr<ofstream> out(new std::ofstream);
  string fileName = "text" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
  out->open(fileName.c_str());
  streams.push_back(out);
}
```

Comment: Using `std::move` works! Saved me a lot of trouble, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `vector::emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, this will create the streams directly in the vector so the copy constructor is not needed:

```
std::vector<std::ofstream> streams;

for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
{
    std::string fileName = "text" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
    streams.emplace_back(std::ofstream{ fileName });
}
```